# Absolute Zero, Charles's Law

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

I think my questions is almost embarresing but anyway: I try to estimate absolute zero (in Celsius) by using Charles's Law. I basically try to reproduce this experiment:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5M8GR6_zIps

So, I have a 100 ml erlenmeyer flask with a stopper and a small glass tube (diameter about 4-5 mm) put into this stopper. I measured the total actual volume of this and found $V_2 = $ 128 ml. I put this in boiling water and measure the temperature. Just like in the video. The glass tube allows to keep the pressure in the flask constant (isobar) to 1 atm. I leave the flask in the water for about 1-2 mins.

Next, I put my finger on the glass tube to seal it and immerse it upside down in cold water (temperature measured to be 18 °C). As the gas inside the flask cools down, the volume of the gas shrinks and sucks water into the flask. After a while (~ 1 min), I lift the flask (which is still upside down in the water bath with the glass tube allowing water to come in and out), so that the water level in the flask equals the water level of the cold bath. In this case, the pressure in the flask should equal ambient pressure (1 atm). Now, I put my finger again on the glass tube to seal it and remove the flask from the water bath. I now measure the volume $\Delta V$ of the water inside the flask.

The gas' volume at 100 °C is $V_2$. As the gas is cooled down to 18 °C its volume is now $V_1 = V_2 - \Delta V$. So, I have the volume of the gas at the same pressure for two different temperatures. By extrapolation I should find absolute zero to be around -250 °C to -280 °C (this is atleast the accuracy I would expect with this experiment). The problem is, I (reproducibly) measure $\Delta V \approx$ 60 ml (approximatly twice as high as I expect), thus $V_1 \approx$ 68 ml. With this I find something like -150 °C as absolute zero, which I consider to be an error that cannot be related to the accuracy.

I basically don't know where I do a mistake. This should not be rocket since. The only thing I could imagine is that my experiment is not actually isobar (or the gas is not an ideal gas), but why? Is there anything I have to pay particular care of?

Comment: Have you tried the experiment without heating?

Answer (score 1):

*With this I find something like -150 °C as absolute zero . . . . . .*

You might have expected better but given all the approximations that have been made eg the large length of the  extrapolation from two data points relatively close together - a small change in the gradient of the line between the two data points leads to a very large change in the intercept on the temperature axis, filling flask with water to the top, using a non-ideal gas with water vapour in it, etc, you have done well.

Comment: Thank you. Well I would agree, but the volume I measure is twice as large as expected. And from what I have seen in the videos (they use the same coditions), the extrapolation gives a reasonable value. I reproducibly measure a volume Delta V which is a way too large to be simply a measurement error. There must be a systematic error. Btw. there should be no water vapour in the flask, but in case the flask was not dry this could be indeed a problem (?)

Comment: Right, this is the problem: some remaining (little amount of) water in the flask evaporated in the hot water bath and condensated in the cold bath. The process was not isobar in this case.